# Need to get the date from the name of the file

Tags: shell, sed, cut

I have a file name abcd_abcd_12302022.csv, I have extracted the date from the file name using

```
cut -c 11-18
```

and the date is 12302022. I have tried below command to be in 12/30/2022 but getting 12_30_2022.

```
echo '20150716' | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1_\2_\3/'
```

I need the output to be 12/30/2022.

Comment: Please show us a few example lines from the file and explain (in your question) how we can identify the date from the file.

Comment: @terdon : this is very simple. we are extracting the date from the filename using cut. example - file_name is abcd_abcd_12302022.csv. using the cut command getting 12302022 date. I just need this to include / in between month, date & year and looks like 12/30/2022. I do not want it to validate it with any other thing. I think we can achieve this using sed or awk, since I am new to unix I am not able to make the proper command.

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and include this information, it gets lost in the comments. Make sure to mention that you want us to get the date from the _name_ of the file, and then clarify exactly what part of the file name we should use. Also, if you're using `ksh`, mention that in the question, as well as what operating system you are using. Do you really mean UNIX? Which one? Or do you mean Linux?

Comment: @terdon : updated the question. Please check

Comment: Change delimiter `echo '20150716' | sed -e 's~\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)~\1/\2/\3~'`

Comment: Thank you.......

Comment: That's great, thank you! So the file name is constant? It is always exactly 4 letters, then an underscore (`_`), then another 4 letters, another underscore and a set of numbers which is the date, ending with `.csv`? And again what operating system is this? Can we assume Linux or is it really Unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same basic idea you had. You were adding the `_` there yourself, so if you change them to `/` it will work. You just need to use a different delimiter for sed's `s///` operator. Here, I am using `s|||` instead:

```
$ echo abcd_abcd_12302022.csv | cut -c 11-18 | sed -E 's|(..)(..)(....)|\1/\2/\3|'
12/30/2022
```

Or, a bit more portable:

```
$ echo abcd_abcd_12302022.csv | cut -c 11-18 | sed  's|\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)|\1/\2/\3|'
12/30/2022
```

Alternatively, you can use `s///`, but you need to escape the `/` you want to insert using `\/`:

```
$ echo abcd_abcd_12302022.csv | cut -c 11-18 | sed -E 's/(..)(..)(....)/\1\/\2\/\3/'
12/30/2022

$ echo abcd_abcd_12302022.csv | cut -c 11-18 | sed  's/\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)/\1\/\2\/\3/'
12/30/2022
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cut` and `sed`, if you have the filename in a variable in the bash shell, you can get your desired format directly within the shell using the [shell's parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```bash
file=abcd_abcd_12302022.csv
printf '%s\n' "${f:10:2}/${f:12:2}/${f:14:4}"
```

It may not matter for interactive use or one-time events, but if you're attempting to extract timestamps from many files, saving the callouts to `cut` and `sed` may save some time.